# mysql.proc has gone corrupt. How can I fix it?

Tags: mysql, debian, corruption

I have a server running Debian 5.0, and MySQL. Suddendly, MySQL stopped working, and after many attempts to fix it, I decided to reinstall it. I installed MySQL 5.1.63, and when started it goes to safe mode. I made some typing, and when I executed `mysql_upgrade` as root, it complained:

```
...
Running 'mysql_fix_privilege_tables'...
ERROR 1548 (HY000) at line 1111: Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1112: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sqlstate 'HY000' set message_text='Unexpected content found in the performance_s' at line 1
ERROR 1548 (HY000) at line 1125: Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
```

I checked the `mysql.proc` table, and it's `comment` column was slightly different from my backup.

```
-- My backup says:
`comment` char(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
-- But it were:
`comment` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
```

So, I restored my mysql database backup, and now they all match, **but** `mysql_upgrade` still trigger the same errors. I also tried do check and repair the `mysql.proc` table, but got no success.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use the `--force` option:

```
mysql_upgrade --force -u root -p
```

Comment: Yes, and I've got the same results.

Comment: It's strange, I just restored another database, and it works. This error isn't preventing MyQL from working...